# how to detect duplicate value selected in dropdown using javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

[image]i have a gridview inside a repeater, and a dropdownlist insid the gridview. now i want no user can select one value twice.my code is

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_test" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:GridView ID="grd_test" runat="server" Style="text-align: center;
                width: 375px;" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="hello" DataField="hello" />
                </Columns>
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="item" DataField="item" />
                </Columns>
                <Columns>                        
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Assign to">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_Assign" runat="server">
                                <asp:ListItem Value="1"> 1</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_Address" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

i want to detect the duplicate value for drodown "drp_Assign".

please see the image the values in comp number should not be duplicate if a user selected "1" for one row then he will not be able to selected same value in second row . if he tries to do then alert message will be shown that you have selected this value already choose another."

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what you need to be achieved in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the repeater as the container, `#rep_test`, and matching all dropdowns inside the container so that user can't select same values.

NOTE : Double check your Repeater ID in your browser as .Net will change it.

UNLESS you change your Client ID Mode to static [.Net 4.0], e.g. :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rep_test" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

REF : http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx

**JQuery:**

```
 $(function() {

    $('#rep_test select').live('change',function(event) {
        var cI = $(this);
        $('#rep_test select option:selected').each(function(i, e) {
            //Check if values match AND if not default AND not match changed item to self
            if ($(e).val() == cI.val() && $(e).val() != 0 && $(e).parent().index() != cI.index()) {

                alert('Duplicate found!');
                cI.val('0');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

**WORKING EXAMPLE :** http://jsfiddle.net/zrcZM/2

Comment: sir thats ok but the id in any databound control will always changed.So the example you have provide me is for same id. but in my case the id always changed so.. please if you have suggestion or help for that. then dont hesitate

Comment: That is why I don't use an ID as my selector, but a Class. So you can use this <asp:DropDownList ID="drp_Assign" runat="server" CSSClass='fDrop'> ...It will get all dropdowns with that css class. Let me know if you understand

Comment: Mmmmm strange. Can you open your page in your browser, copy the generated html and scripts, paste it in http://jsfiddle.net . So I can see what's the problem.

Comment: *Remember to call the jquery script at the end of the page / on dom ready. And/OR you can change your event bind to .live. this will work for dynamic html content, see link : http://jsfiddle.net/zrcZM/1/

Comment: sir please review my code the dropdown is inside a grid and grid is in a repeater it clearly shows i have to repeat grid so your logic is not useful for this condition i have to do it according to id only..

Comment: See updated answer. My answer it totally relevant to your question. You must just implement it correct. If you look at my updated answer it will user the main container, your repeater [check the ID on the front end and change accordingly], and will now get all the dropdowns in your repeater. Hope this helps. Let me know if you still struggle.